# Present a View Controller modally when selected in Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this pretty standard Tab Bar Controller setup:

```
UIViewController *homeViewController = [[PLOTHomeViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *upcomingViewController = [[PLOTUpcomingViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *checkInViewController = [[PLOTCheckInViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *watchlistViewController = [[PLOTWatchlistViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController *profileViewController = [[PLOTProfileViewController alloc] init];

PLOTNavigationController *homeNavVC = [[PLOTNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeViewController];
PLOTNavigationController *upcomingNavVC = [[PLOTNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:upcomingViewController];
PLOTNavigationController *checkInNavVC = [[PLOTNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:checkInViewController];
PLOTNavigationController *watchlistNavVC = [[PLOTNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:watchlistViewController];
PLOTNavigationController *profileNavVC = [[PLOTNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];

self.tabBarController = [[PLOTTabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:homeNavVC, upcomingNavVC, checkInNavVC, watchlistNavVC, profileNavVC, nil];
```

However, I'm trying to work out how, when the user selects the middle tab (checkInViewController), I can present that View Controller modally (fullscreen)? I'd maybe imagine something in the `viewDidAppear` method in that VC, but I'm not sure if you can present yourself modally, if you're a VC? What's the best approach for this?

Comment: Does setting self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed inside checkInView's init method do what you need?

Comment: @neal that is really awesome, and I suppose it gives me the end result, but I guess I can't really "dismiss" it like I would a modal...or can I? (and it doesn't animate up)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[self presentViewController:checkInViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then hide the tab and navigation bars in the destination view controller's `viewWillAppear:`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: but at what point do I run this? I'd like it to happen when the user selects that Tab Bar Item in the tabbarcontroller

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your question a bit--when a user selects the `checkInViewController` you want that view controller to be presented and the top and bottom navigation/tab bars hidden?

Comment: Yep, almost entirely like the Instagram app does, ie. You hit the tab and a full screen modal overlays everything